# MySQL/PHP Returning Blank Error Message

Tags: mysql, php

I am using the following code to delete a record. It works fine, but MySQL always returns a blank error message. PHP returns "Error: " instead of "1 Record Dropped".

```
$eventid = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect, $_POST['eventid']));
mysqli_query($dbconnect,"DELETE FROM Events WHERE EventID='$eventid' LIMIT 1");
if (!mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbconnect));
}
echo "1 Record Dropped";
```

When I use the same PHP code and change the SQL to a SELECT or INSERT INTO command instead of a DELETE command, I receive the correct response from PHP.

Comment: There is something wrong on that code: you are querying mysql twice, only check for errors once, and you do not show the actual query text of the second one ($sql). You can also print the number of records dropped with mysqli_affected_rows().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! @jynus was exactly correct.  Here is the fix:

```
$eventid = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect, $_POST['eventid']));
$sql="DELETE FROM Events WHERE EventID='$eventid' LIMIT 1";
if (!mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbconnect));
}
echo mysqli_affected_rows() . " Record(s) Dropped";
```